# Creation of 2 form pages

Tags: angular

I created a page with 2 fields (first name and last name):

```
<div class="box-body">
  <form novalidate #formRef="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formRef.value)">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label>First name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" ngModel #firstNameRef="ngModel" required [class.ctrl-error] = "firstNameRef.touched &&
        firstNameRef?.errors?.required" minlength="3">
        <div *ngIf="firstNameRef.touched &&
        firstNameRef?.errors?.required" class="error-message">
          The first name is required.
        </div>
        <div class="error-message" *ngIf="firstNameRef.touched &&
        firstNameRef?.errors?.minlength">
          You should enter minimum
          {{firstNameRef?.errors?.minlength.requiredLength}}
          characters into first name, but you entered only
          {{firstNameRef?.errors?.minlength.actualLength}} character(s).
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label>Last name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" ngModel #lastNameRef="ngModel">
      </div>

    </div>

    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" [disabled]="formRef.invalid">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

When the user clicks on the button "submit", I will wish to receive a second page with a new field to complete. This field is named `country`.

I don't understand how to create this second page? I have to create a new HTML.component with a new form?

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
<label>Your country</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" ngModel #countryNameRef="ngModel">
</div>
```

How to interact the button "submit" with the second page?

In fact, I am stuck on the way to create the second page. My code is also on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tuqspb?file=src/app/registration-form/registration-form.component.html).

Thanks

Comment: You can generate a new component from the cli with the following command:

Comment: ng g c componentname

Comment: I can not recommend you to fill a form on separate pages. create a wizard-like component that shows and hides its parts and `formGroup` surrounds them all.